# Vlc http interface keep asking password

Tags: vlc, remote, lua

I am trying to control vlc from browser or my android phone. I read wiki vlc. And I believe I did everthing right. Enabled Http interface, set a password. But when I go to localhost:8080 browser asks me username and password and I write and it asks me over and over again. Eventually I hit "esc" and 401 Unauthorized come up. 
I left username blank and tried "dummy" too but nothing changed.
I tried both vlc 2.1.4 and vlc nightly build
I am using ubuntu 14.04
Thanks for help

Comment: I installed windows 7 on my laptop. VLC web interface worked smoothly in Windows. So the problem is not about my laptop or network